# does DOM rendering happen asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, asynchronous, svg

I have some code which gets triggered in a callback on mouse scroll on an SVG 
which makes some transformations to SVG (for zooming in and out to a point).
For some huge SVGs , the performance is sluggish and I want to improve this
and I am trying to measure the time taken from the time scroll starts till the time rendering is done.
I have the following code

```
var timerStart = Date.now();
//some calculations
svgElement.setAttribute("transform",newTransform);
console.log("rendered:", Date.now()-timerStart);
```

However I can see that rendering happens even after the log is printed.
I assumed that DOM manipulations are synchronous(javascript runtime is single threaded), it seems this is not the case?Is there some rendering queue which asynchronously does the rendering?
How can I accurately measure the performance of rendering in such cases?

Comment: Rendering happens asynchronously. You can't measure it from a script although you may be able to do so with the browser's built in debugging tools.

Comment: `trasnform` <-- That is an interesting spelling

Comment: I haven't tried playing with it, but *maybe* [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) could solve your problem. It's supposed to be executed just before the repaint.

Comment: @epascarello thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Amit Thanks I will try that, can you give provide some sources on this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendering doesn't just happen asynchronously, it happens *concurrently* (i.e. in another thread). So you can't accurately measure it from the JavaScript thread.

However, most modern browsers allow for profiling from the developer tools provided by them, to see what causes each render/layout/reflow and how to optimize your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, can you provide some sources?I would like to understand more about this topic.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/ <- This is an excellent article.

Comment: I found this source http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/ saying that DOM is not thread safe, I wonder how rendering can happen concurrently if that is the case, is it that rendering works on the render tree(which I assume should be thread safe) and not DOM tree?